# How can I remove all characters after a specified word and before a period in a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this string:

```
1_plex_light-blue-striped_imagegroup.jpg?v=1581100432
```

Sometimes it looks like this:

```
1_plex_light-blue-striped_imagegroup_d6f347cf-1440-45ef-955d-144ge18d0a00.jpg?v=1581100432
```

The string is made up of different bits that my code uses to help decide where and when to display the image.

- 1 (order in group of images)
- plex (product name)
- light-blue-striped (colour)
- imagegroup (let's my code know the image is part of a group

**Code:**

This code is inside a function that is triggered when a colour box is clicked. I pass in the colour of the box that was clicked, followed by the word "_imagegroup", and use the string to help be filter the images with the selected colour from the group of images I started out with.

```
    var imagesArray = makeProductImagesArray();

    function filterImageByColourAndGroupType(image) {
          return image.masterImagePath.includes(`${colour}_imageset.`);
    }

    var filteredArray = imagesArray.filter(filterImageByColourAndGroupType);

    filteredArray.sort((a, b) => a.masterImagePath.replace(/\D/g,'').localeCompare(b.masterImagePath.replace(/\D/g,'')));
```

**Issue:**

Sometimes the match fails because a random string like "d6f347cf-1440-45ef-955d-144ge18d0a00", is added to the image path.

How can I ensure that my filter only gives me back images that match this format:

```
light-blue-striped_imagegroup.
```

The filter needs to think the string that is added after "imagegroup" doesn't exist. It would see this:

```
1_plex_light-blue-striped_imagegroup.jpg?v=1581100432
```

And to totally ignore:

```
_d6f347cf-1440-45ef-955d-144ge18d0a00
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the code for filterImageByFlavourAndSetType? Your code snippet only has the code for filterImageByColourAndGroupType.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been: filterImageByColourAndGroupType. I've edited my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Lookbehind assertion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions) to match for characters preceded by imagegroup:

```js
const str = '1_plex_light-blue-striped_imagegroup_d6f347cf-1440-45ef-955d-144ge18d0a00.jpg?v=1581100432';
console.log(str);
const regex = "/(?<=imagegroup).*\./"

const newStr = str.replace(regex, '.');
console.log(newStr)
```

EDIT:
`Lookbehind assertion` has a form of `(?<=y)x` and it matches "x" only if "x" is preceded by "y", to give simple example:

```js
const str = 'matchNOT but matchTHIS';

//this will look for anything containing the word 'match', 
//but only if it's preceded by the word 'but'; so 'match' before 'but' will be ignored
// and 'match' after 'but' will be captured.
const newStr = str.match(/(?<=but).*match.*/);

console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: give comparable example of strings so that i can understand what to keep and what to remove

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex. Something like this would work:

```
function filterImageByColourAndGroupType(image) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`[0-9]+_.*_${colour}_imagegroup[_.*]?`);
  return image.masterImagePath.match(regex) != null;
}
```

This will match both `1_plex_light-blue-striped_imagegroup.jpg?v=1581100432` and `1_plex_light-blue-striped_imagegroup_d6f347cf-1440-45ef-955d-144ge18d0a00.jpg?v=1581100432`.

You might need to tweak the exact regex a bit based on the specific constraints of the values (which I don't know and am only guessing at here) but this should get you started.